# PHP > Array > assign value to text key duplicate the key

Tags: php, arrays, key, duplicates

My code:

```
$a['page'] = 1;
function change($a) {
$a['page'] = 2;
}
```

My output:

```
$a['page'] = 1;
$a['page'] = 2;
```

Why am I get two keys 'page'?
I was expecting the function changed the value.

Comment: What is the result of print_r $a?

Comment: this code is not complete, you can't have `$a['page'] = 1; $a['page'] = 2;` as output as you're not printing anything. Where's your `echo`/`var_dump` statement ?

Comment: Show us the complete code (including how you call the function).

Comment: the variable $a inside the function has the scope only for the function and the variable $a above it has a global scope so php treats them as different and thats why they can have same index.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a['page'] = 1;

function change($a) {
    return $a['page'] = 2;
}

echo change($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pass $a by reference instead and it would work as expected. It would be slower but not significantly so, given the function.

```
$a['page'] = 1;

function change(&$a) {
    $a['page'] = 2;
}

change($a);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
```